# Find an element in Rotated Sorted Array with duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This code is the solution to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array-ii/

The logic that I applied here works fine for finding an element in a rotated sorted array without duplicate elements. Can someone please tell me what modifications are required to make it work for array with duplicate elements?

[2,5,6,0,0,1,2], target = 0 output: true
[2,5,6,0,0,1,2], target = 3 output: false

```java
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        if(nums.length== 0) return -1;

        int left= 0; int right= nums.length -1;

        // find the pivot element i.e, the one that breaks the sorted order of the array
        while(left< right){
            int mid= left+ (right- left)/ 2;
            // if mid< right that means this much part of the array is sorted
            // then do binary search on left and mid
            if(nums[mid]< nums[right])
                right= mid;
            // if mid> right that means this part of the array is not sorted
            // then do binary search on mid+1 to right
            else
                left= mid+ 1;
        }
        int pivot= left;
        int index= -1;
        // if target is between pivot till end then call binary search on that
        if(target>= nums[pivot] && target<= nums[nums.length- 1]){
            index= binarySearch(nums, target, pivot, nums.length- 1);
        }    
        // if target is between start and pivot then call binary search on that
        else{
            index= binarySearch(nums, target, 0, pivot -1);
        }  

        return index;
    }

    // binary search returning index of the mid element
    public int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target, int s, int e){
        while(s<= e){
            int mid= s + (e-s)/ 2;
            if(nums[mid]== target)
                return mid;
            else if(target> nums[mid])
                s= mid+ 1;
            else
                e= mid -1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give the test input, the array that contains the duplicate elements?

Comment: Does your code not work? You should return the bool `(index != -1)` instead of the index itself, but I don't think you need to change anything else.

Comment: I am getting time limit exceeded.

Comment: I don't think this algorithm will give you the correct result for duplicates. But time limit exceeded seems to be a little strange. What I can tell you is that with duplicates binary search won't help you, worst case is O(n), so you can just scan the array. E.g. lets say left = mid = right = 2. You cannot say if the left half or the right half contains other numbers than 2, in the worst case you have to look at all the numbers, no matter how clever your binary search is.

Comment: I have to do it o(log(n)). So I guess it has to be binary search in some modified way.

Comment: Maybe you can get an average of O(logn) if the number of duplicates isn't too high. If all test cases consist of arrays with just x and one y, then you have no chance.

Comment: I tried to do a simple scan O(n) and I passed all test cases... `public boolean search(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i : nums)
            if (i == target)
                return true;
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your algorithm is that you are not sure if you find the exact pivot when its value is repeated.
For example for the array `[8,9,2,2,4,5,6]` your algorithm find as pivot the element in the 4th position (counting from 0 is the element 3).
In this way the left part of the array will be `[8,9,2]` which is not sorted and therefore the binary search doesn't work.

A very simply solution is to find two pivots (let's call left_pivot and right_pivot).
The right_pivot is exactly the one you are already finding and is defined as "an element that has the lowest value of the array".\
The left_pivot is defined as "an element that has the highest value of the array" and you find with an easy modification:

```java
       while(left< right){
            int mid= left+ (right- left)/ 2;
            if (mid * 2 < right)
                mid = mid + 1
            // if mid< right that means this much part of the array is sorted
            // then do binary search on left and mid
            if(nums[mid]< nums[right])
                right= mid-1;
            // if mid> right that means this part of the array is not sorted
            // then do binary search on mid+1 to right
            else
                left= mid;
        }
```

Then a binary search in the left part of the array will be done from index 0 to index left_pivot (instead of pivot-1) and the one in the right part of the array from index right_pivot to length-1

Comment: why did you do-

if (mid * 2 < right)
                mid = mid + 1

. Also shouldn't it be (mid * 2 <= right)? 
Why mid*2?

Comment: @DhananjayTyagi I did it to round the mid at the higher value (let's say left = 7 and right = 10 I want mid to be 9 and not 8, otherwise you will remain stuck in an infinite loop when you have right = left + 1). I'm not a java dev and I don't know the math functions otherwise I would have written `mid = ceil(double(left+right)/2)`
And it shouldn't be `(mid * 2 <= right)` because when, for example, left=4 and right=8 I want mid=6  and not mid=7